# Ruby: From a String to an Array of JSONS

Tags: json, ruby, sinatra

I have a string retrieved from a post form which looks something like that

```
"[{"Name": "David", "ID": "2"}, {"Name": "Logan" , "ID": "3"}]"
```

I would like to iteratively access every JSON object on its own. Or Ideally, convert this string to an array of JSONs in Ruby. Any idea on how to do that?

Comment: Use the [standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
require 'json'
=> true
JSON.parse('[{"Name": "David", "ID": "2"}, {"Name": "Logan" , "ID": "3"}]')
=>
[
    [0] {
        "Name" => "David",
          "ID" => "2"
    },
    [1] {
        "Name" => "Logan",
          "ID" => "3"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

To convert the [JSON string](https://www.json.org/index.html) that was returned from the API into a Ruby array of JSON strings I would do something like this:

```
json = '[{"Name": "David", "ID": "2"}, {"Name": "Logan" , "ID": "3"}]'

require 'json'

ruby_array_of_ruby_hashes = JSON.parse(json)
ruby_array_of_json = ruby_array_of_ruby_hashes.map(&:to_json)
#=> ["{\"Name\":\"David\",\"ID\":\"2\"}","{\"Name\":\"Logan\",\"ID\":\"3\"}"]
```

Or short:

```
JSON.parse(json).map(&:to_json)
```